# VBA Excel: Sub procedure to change caption in a UserForm control

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm creating a user form that shows the value(numeric) of the last used cell in a column.

I'm just guessing on how to do it but it doesn't work, this is what I got:

```
Sub show()

UserForm1.show

'xTotal is the name of the label control and B4 is the column with a list of numbers:

UserForm1.xTotal.Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b4").End(xlDown)

End Sub
```

I know this is elementary stuff, I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: What result does this code give?

Comment: It shows the form but the label is blank, nothing in it. It should show the last number in the column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a caption to a range, which is what your code is doing (though not your intention). You must set the caption to the value of the range -

```
UserForm1.xTotal.Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b4").End(xlDown).Value
Userform1.Show
```

You'll also want to set the caption before showing the userform.